# How to remove characters in a string?

Tags: c#, string

How to remove the some characters in a string ..

```
string s="testpage\information.xml"
```

I need only information.xml how to do that?

Comment: Is `string newString = "information.xml";` good enough? Please, specify  what you need

Comment: Is that always going to be a file path that you want to extract the file name from?

Comment: @user1727822 any more problem or problem solved? Did you check the answers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`System.IO.Path` may help you with this since the string contains a file path information. In your case, you may use `Path.GetFileName(string path)` to get the file name from a string.

**Example**

```
string s = @"testpage\information.xml";
string filename = Path.GetFileName(s);
//MessageBox.Show(filename);
```

Thanks,

I hope you find this helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the value that will be in `s` is always a file path, use the `Path` class to extract the file name

```
var filename = Path.GetFileName(s);
```

Answer (score 0):

File path is of the form

`aaaa\bbb\ccc\dddd\information.xml`

To retrieve the last string, you can divide your string using the delimiter `\`

```
String path = @"aaaa\bbb\ccc\dddd\information.xml";
String a[] = path.Split('\\');
```

This will give String array as `["aaaa", "bbb", "ccc", "dddd", "information.xml"]`

You can retrieve the filename as

```
String filename = a[a.Length-1];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using file paths, see the [Path.GetFileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename.aspx) Method
It will not check whether the file exists or not. So it will be faster.

```
s = Path.GetFileName(s);
```

If you need to check whether file exists, use File.Exists class.

Another way is to use String.Split() method

```
string[] arr = s.Split('\\');
if(arr.Length > 0)
{
  s = arr[arr.Length - 1];
}
```

Another way is to use RegEx

```
s = Regex.Match(s, @"[^\\]*$").Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is going to be a file path, then you can use the `System.IO.Path` class ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.aspx)) to extract the filename.

```
string s = "testpage\information.xml"
var filename = Path.GetFilename(s);
```

Comment: If you down vote an answer, please at least give a reason why. This is a valid answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

If it's always right of the backslash separator then you can use:

```
if (s.Contains(@"\")) 
     s= s.Substring(s.IndexOf(@"\") + 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is what you want:

```
var result=s.Substring(s.LastIndexOf(@"\") + 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following line of codes to get file extension.

```
string filePath = @"D:\Test\information.xml";
string extention = Path.GetExtension(filePath);
```

If you need file name alone use,

```
string filePath  = @"D:\Test\information.xml";
string filename = Path.GetFilename(filePath );
```

Comment: For this example, extention is ".xml"

Answer (score 0):

Use string.Replcae

```
string s = @"testpage\information.xml";
s = s.Replace(@"testpage\\",""); // replace  'testpage\' with empty string
```

You will get Output => s=information.xml

@ is need only because you have backslash in your string

For further reading about STRING REPLACE

http://www.dotnetperls.com/replace

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.replace.aspx

Answer (score -1):

In C++ you can do something like this. Basically search for "/" or "\" from right to left of the path and crop the string starting from the first occurance of the delimiter:

```
string ExtractFileName(const string& strPathFileName)
{
    size_t npos;
    string strOutput = strPathFileName;
    if(strPathFileName.rfind(L'/', npos) || strPathFileName.rfind(L'\\', npos))
    {
        strOutput = strPathFileName.substr(npos+1);
    }
    return strOutput;
}
```